# Save multiple rows from single Access form where only two field values change

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I feel this question has been asked a million times but i can't seem to find what i need from the answers.

My wife has an audit spreadsheet (see image) that she would like made in to a database.  I am relatively new to Access, but not to databases, so i know what i want but am struggling to get it.

[image]

In the image, you can see the 4 columns in the top left.  "Date" would be from a date picker, "Area", "Auditor" and "Shift Leader" would be from a drop down list.

Each field under each category is fixed, so i can present the title of each field using a list box that pulls the relevant title name from a table.
All titles needs to have a score and comment assigned and then all of this information needs to be committed to the "tblAuditItems" table in individual rows, with each row having the "Date", "Area", "Auditor" and "Shift Leader" added.

What i feel i need to do, is to have all titles set when the form loads, my wife would then fill in the "Date" field along with the other 3 and then click a button to commit all of this data to the table.  A kind of "Add records" or "Generate records" button, with a loop to run through each title.
She would then go through the form, adding the information to the "Score" and "Comments" boxes and click "Save records" at the end.

**UPDATE: --**  As far as table structure goes, all of the titles are held in a table called "tblCodes" along with other things.  In that table, there is the OID, the title text and a 'codeset' that will allow me to group them when reporting.
The date, score and comments are fields of their own in tblAuditItems, the auditor names are stored in a tblAuditors table and are looked up by the Auditor field in tblAuditItems.

Essentially, i dont want the tblAuditItems to hold any text other than 'Comments'.  I find it far easier for building dynamic reports. **-- :UPDATE**

Can anyone offer any advice on how to best achieve this?

Thanks in advance, i have until tomorrow..... :(

Comment: Did you create the tables needed?

Comment: Yes - The database was created by me.

Comment: It depends on your table structure. How are the scores, comments and text of each item stored? Since you say they are "fixed", then in theory the entire form could be a single record in a single table. That's probably not the most flexible/extensible/normalised solution but it's the easiest. It also means the whole form would be automatically loaded and saved to one record just using standard ControlSource binding of fields in the form. No need for VBA code for loading and saving to multiple records.

Comment: Updated the OP.